# Get realtime data from Firestore using Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, axios

I am using the Axios api but I am encountering a problem. I only have Firestore calls in the backend and not the frontend. I'm making a chat app using React and Firestore and I can't seem to figure out how to get continuous data with an Axios call and not a Firestore one.

It only updates one time and doesn't continuously stream. Do I have to just call Firestore in the frontend?

Here is my code calling the axios function from the redux action.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getChatList();
    this.setState({
      chats: Object.values(this.props.allMessages),
    });
  }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!equal(this.props.allMessages, prevProps.allMessages)) {
      this.props.getChatList();
      this.setState({
        chats: Object.values(this.props.allMessages),
      });
    }
  }
```

And this is the data action function that uses the Axios call.

```
export const getChatList = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: "LOADING_DATA" });
  API.get("messages")
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "GET_MESSAGES",
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch(() =>
      dispatch({
        type: "GET_MESSAGES",
        payload: null,
      })
    );
};
```

Comment: This is because `this.props.getChatList();` in `componentdidmount` is only called once and it updates the chat first time. You will need a mechanism that makes continuous calls to your backend to get the chats. Try using setInterval to make continuous calls to backend. Something like `setInterval(() => this.props.getChatList(), 2000)` in your `componentdidmount` so that call to `getChatList()` is made every two seconds

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as Community wiki, based on @ShauryaMittal comment.

It seems that the issue is related to your `this.props.getChatList();`. On your `componentdidmount`', it's only called once, so, it only updates the chat the first time. You will need a mechanism that makes continuous calls to your backend to get the chats.

One option is to try the `seetInterval()` method. This method - as explained fully [here](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/setinterval-in-react-components-using-hooks) - runs some code after specific intervals of time, as specified through the second parameter. For example, try using `setInterval()` to make continuous calls to backend. Something like `setInterval(() => this.props.getChatList(), 2000)` in your `componentdidmount` so that a call to `getChatList()` is made every two seconds.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an extensive amount of reads to the Firestore?

Comment: Hi @EnglishBanana if you want to get continous data from your Firestore database, you will be getting more amounts of read. This solution is an example of what can be done, but please, bear in mind that any way that you will be implementing to get updates and retrieve of data will raise the number of reads. Of course, you can always raise the timing for the function to be run.